# Odd formatting in SQL Injection exploits?

Tags: sql, security

I have been trying to learn more about SQL Injection attacks. I understand the principle, but when I actually look at some of these attacks I don't know how they are doing what they are doing.

There often seem to be uneven quotes, and a lot of obfuscation via HEX characters.

I don't get the HEX characters..., surely they are translated back to ASCII by the browser, so what is the point?

However, I am mainly confused by the odd quoting. I am having trouble finding an example right now, however it usually seems that the quoting will end at some point before the end of the statement, when I would have thought it would be at the end?

Perhaps an example is the common use of '1 or 1=1

What is such a statement doing?

Comment: Good question.  Its sad to see that i'm the only one who has posted that has actually used this technique in a sql injection exploit.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't get the HEX characters...,
>   surely they are translated back to
>   ASCII by the browser

Nope.

> However, I am mainly confused by the
>   odd quoting. I am having trouble
>   finding an example right now, however
>   it usually seems that the quoting will
>   end at some point before the end of
>   the statement, when I would have
>   thought it would be at the end?

Imagine you're building inline SQL instead of using parameter substitution as you should.  We'll use a make-believe language that looks a lot like PHP for no particular reason.

```
$sql = "delete from foo where bar = '" + $param + "'";
```

So, now, imagine that `$param` gets set by the browser as such...

```
$param = "' or 1=1 --"
```

(We're pretending like `--` is the SQL comment sequence here.  If it's not there's ways around that too)

So, now, what is your SQL after the string substitution is done?

```
delete from foo where bar = '' or 1=1 --'
```

Which will delete every record in `foo`.

This has been purposefully simple, but it should give you a good idea of what the uneven quotes are for.

Comment: @Rook - Most of the answer has nothing to do with hex encoding.  I just corrected his assumption about browsers and moved on.  Also, I don't see how his question was specific to mysql, so you argument about mysql_query is fairly spurious as well.

Comment: This does not answer the question,  you should read one of the sql injection exploits that I posted.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that we have a form where we submit a form with a name field.  name was used in a variable, $Name. You then run this query:

```
INSERT INTO Students VALUES ( '$Name' )
```

It will be translated into:

```
INSERT INTO Students VALUES ( 'Robert' );  DROP TABLE STUDENTS; --')
```

The -- is a comment delimiter. After that everything will be ignored. The ' is used to delimit string literals.

To use hex chars in an attack has some reasons. One of the is the obfuscation, other one to bypass some naive security measures.

Comment: Batched queries now a days aren't supported by the most ubiquitous sql servers. Also -- is not the only comment delimiter, e.g. MySQL has /*... And using hex encoding is very rarely for obfuscation, as you cannot hide your actual query, only the values within it. It is mainly used because of the lack of necessity for single quotes around hexed value, so when you have complicated injection, you don't have to worry about the number of quotes, and working out the whole logic for the injection query

Comment: This is a SQL Server example of sql injection.  This will never work with `mysq_query()` and it doesn't address hex encoding.

Comment: Exploits of a mom, I approve.

Comment: Reference to XKCD is cool and everything but... it doesn't even answer the question. Why would it be upvoted?

Comment: @Vincent Savard sure i did, for example i explained why odd quoting and some reasons for hex encoding.

Comment: @Cyber-Gaurd-Design: hex as encoding is as well used for obfuscation. You hide the query, specially in malicious js
from a worm.js that was active in the past:
GET SomeParameter/?’;DECLARE%20@S%20CHAR(4000);SET%20@S=CAST(0×4445434C4152452040542076617
...
437572736F72%20AS%20CHAR(4000));EXEC(@S); HTTP/1.1

Comment: @Rook why assume that he is using mysql if he didn't ask about mysql and if he didn't tag about mysql.. There is just mysql in the world?

Comment: @VP that example has nothing to do with obfuscation,  just print out @s,  that technique is used to to avoid quote marks,  Try writing exploit sometime. (http://www.exploit-db.com/author/?a=628)

Comment: @Rook i do it since you were in the kindergarten http://securitytracker.com/alerts/2002/Dec/1005847.html

Comment: @Rook http://isc.sans.edu/diary.html?storyid=9397 maybe you can be more humble and learn with the others ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There are cases where quote marks are prohibited with sql injection.  In this case an attacker has to use an encoding method,  such as hex encoding for his strings.  For instance `'/etc/passwd'` can be written as`0x2f6574632f706173737764` which doesn't require quote marks.  Here is an example of a vulnerable query where quote marks are prohibited. :

`mysql_query("select name from users where id=".addslashes($_GET[id]));`

If you want to use a mysql function like `load_file()`,  then you have to use hex encoding.

PoC:`/vuln.php?id=1 union select load_file(0x2f6574632f706173737764)`

In this case /etc/passwd is being read and will be the 2nd row.

Here is a variation on the hex encode function that I use in  my MySQL SQL Injection exploits:

```
function charEncode($string){
    $char="char(";
    $size=strlen($string);
    for($x=0;$x<$size;$x++){
        $char.=ord($string[$x]).",";
    }
    $char[strlen($char)-1]=")%00";
    return $char;
}
```

I use this exact method for [exploiting HLStats 1.35](http://securityreason.com/securityalert/2064).  I have also used this function  in my [php nuke exploit](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/12510/) to bypass xss filters for writing `<?php?>` to the disk using `into outfile`.  Its important to note that `into outfile` is a query operator that does not accept the output to a function or a hex encoded string,  it will only accept a quoted string as a path,  thus in the vulnerable query above `into outfile` cannot be used by an attacker.  Where as `load_file()` is a function call and a hex encoding can be used.

Comment: Excellent answer. I'm curious, why does MySQL interpret `0x2f6574632f706173737764` as `/etc/passwd` ?

Comment: @Vincent Savard 0x is apart of the syntax to many languages.  PHP interpreters the value as a number.  MySQL sees an ascii string,  where 2f is `/` and 65 is the letter `e` and 74 is `t`...  and so on.

Comment: @Rook : Yes,  I knew about 0x, but I was surprised it was interpreted as a string (PostgreSQL interprets is as a number, and so do every language I know). Thank you for the precision.

Comment: @Vincent Savard Your welcome,  I'm glad you liked my post. Good call i didn't know that about postgresql.  In that case I think you can use the `chr()` function instead.

Comment: Hm strange since you are 'the only one who has posted that has actually used this technique in a sql injection exploit', your example injection wouldn't work because you didn't return the left select query false. Also load_file and into outfile work only on a server running as root, which is quite rare. And if the $_GET variable was a string, you would need to escape the quoting, so your injection wouldn't work. Lastly you didn't address the question about uneven quoting at all. Oh and addslashes is actually exploitable by usage of special encoded characters, so you could use into outfile

Comment: you did answer about hex very well but it was just part of his question.. btw load_file into outfile is really rare to exploit since, mysqld runs default as less privileged user (everybody uses mysql_safe as init script)

Comment: @Cyber-Guard Design are you running an ubuntu system?  If this is the case the apparmor will prevent you from reading /etc/passwd.  I have broken apparmor in my phpnuke exploit, and i have worked with canonical on a patch,  which is still in the testing phase.   Also no,  `into outfile '/var/www'`  works if you have global write prilviges enabled on your web root,  or if you have apparmor disabled.  MySQL should never run as root.

Comment: @VP Not really, hundreds maybe eve thousands of exploits have used `into outfile` and `load_file()`,  you mysql almost always runs as mysqld and thats fine if the webroot has a global write directory.  But even in this case AppArmor will stop you if you are on an ubuntu system.  So thats why i broke AppArmor in my phpnuke exploit which works a completely default system.  (at least for now)

Comment: @Cyber-Guard Design  You are also incorrect about the usage of union selects the first select statement can return any number of rows,  even zero rows as long as the number of columns are the same.

Comment: @Rook yes hundred, thousands in your dream maybe. You should grant manually the rights to do so.. it's not a default feature, nobody enable, it's bad practice to enable. Let's keep focus mysql is not even cited in his question, so if your world is mysql, ask a question and answer yourself.

Comment: @Rook i do it since you were in the kindergarten http://securitytracker.com/alerts/2002/Dec/1005847.html
@Rook i do write exploits for living and i do presentations at blackhat http://www.blackhat.com/html/bh-europe-07/bh-eu-07-speakers.html, but it's not the topic.. neither mysql or your exploit ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As for the uneven quoting; sql injection occurs where the coder didn't sanitize user input for dangerous characters such as single quotes - consider following statement

```
SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$_GET["user"]' and password='$_GET["pass"]'
```

if I know that valid user is 'admin' and insert the `'or 1=1` I will get following

```
SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='admin' and password='something' or 1=1
```

This will result in returning the query alway true, because the left side of the expression will always be true, regardless of the value of the password.

This is the most simple example of sql injection, and ofter you will find that the attacker won't need to use the quote at all, or maybe comment the rest of the query out with comment delimiter such as `--` or `/*`, if there are more parameters passed after the injection point.

As for the HEX encoding, there may be several reasons, avoiding filtering, it is simply easier to use hex encoded values, because you don't need to worry about quoting all your values in a query.
This is for instance useful if you want to use `concat` to co-notate two fields together like so:

```
inject.php?id=1 and 1=0 union select 1,2,concat(username,0x3a3a,password) from admin
```

Which would providing 3rd row is visible one, return for isntance `admin::admin`. If I didn't use hex encoding, I would have to do this:

```
 inject.php?id=1 and 1=0 union select 1,2,concat(username,'::',password) from admin
```

This could be problem with aforementioned `addslashes` function, but also with poorly written regex sanitization functions or if you have very complicated query.

Sql injection is very wide topic, and what I've covered is hardly even an introduction through.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Rook. It didn't went deep in hex encoding as you but he answered the question more than you did. I mean he went through the whole question, not just one topic.

Comment: okay unlike @VP's answer which was ripped out of a comic book this is actually a real attack scenario.  And its nearly identical to mine.  But i still think `load_file()` and `into outfile` are more useful examples.

Comment: Cyber-Guard Design  You should trust me when i say MySQL doesn't need to be root,  even when apparmor is being used: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/05/11/phpnuke_infection_purged/