# Is mysql_real_escape_string() unsafe against hexadecimal encoded data?

Tags: php, mysql

We know that all user input must be escape by `mysql_real_escape_string()` function before executing on mysql in php script. And know that this function insert a \ before any `'` or `"` character in user input.  suppose following code:

```
$_POST['username'] = 'aidan';
$_POST['password'] = "' OR ''='";

// Query database to check if there are any matching users
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']."' AND password='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']."'";

mysql_query($query);

// This means the query sent to MySQL would be:
echo $query;
```

this code is safe.

But I find out if user enters her inputs with hexadecimal format then `mysql_real_escape_string()` can not do any thing and user can execute her sql injection easily.  in bellow `27204f522027273d27` is same `' OR ''='` but in hex formated and sql execute without problem :

```
$_POST['username'] = 'aidan';
$_POST['password'] = "27204f522027273d27";

// Query database to check if there are any matching users
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']."' AND password='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']."'";

mysql_query($query);

// This means the query sent to MySQL would be:
echo $query;
```

But whether this is true and if answer is yes how we can prevent sql injection in this way?

Comment: When dealing with issues like vulnerabilities, it is best to provide a sample of your code (simplified, if necessary, to demonstrate the issue) and input which triggers the problem you are seeing.

Comment: Please demonstrate how specifically an attacker can bypass `mysql_real_escape_string` by using hexadecimal notation.

Comment: @deceze: An example of how hexadecimal encoding can be used to circumvent escaping [can be found in this answer by Rook](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4262043/106769).

Comment: @Ahmad: Huge improvement on the question with that edit!  Thank you!  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Ahmad The example you give does *not* demonstrate any problem, running that query works as expected.

Comment: @Conspicuous The example you link to by Rook is significantly different and does not even use `mysql_real_escape_string` (though the problem demonstrated probably affects it as well). You still have not demonstrated a case where a *correctly applied* `mysql_real_escape_string` has problems with hexadecimal characters.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5521/discussion-between-conspicuous-compiler-and-deceze)

Comment: "this code is safe." is not true, simply escaping single and double quotes don't ensure the query cannot be hijacked. Check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBVThFwdYTc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), odds are you would be better served using a prepared statement.

For your specific case, try this code:

```
/*
Somewhere earlier in your application, you will have to set $dbh
 by connecting to your database using code like:
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $DBuser, $DBpass);
*/

$_POST['username'] = 'aidan';
$_POST['password'] = "' OR ''='";

$user = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// Query database to check if there are any matching users
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user=? AND password=?";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $user);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $password);
$stmt->execute();
```

This does require you to use PDO for your database interaction, but that's a good thing overall.  [Here's a question discussing the differences between PDO and mysqli statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Also see [this StackOverflow question which is remarkably similar to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353666/php-is-mysql-real-escape-string-sufficient-for-cleaning-user-input) and the accepted answer, from which I poached some of this answer.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. Yes, prepared statements *are* preferable, but the question was something different. Also, PDO will fall back onto `mysql_real_escape_string`-like behavior if the database does not support prepared statements, so it's still an issue.

Comment: @deceze: I'm afraid that's inaccurate.  As I detailed in our chat, this resolves the likely vector of attack.  Moreover, any version of MySQL released in the last decade supports PDOs.  Falling back to `mysql_real_escape_string()` would never realistically happen.  I don't think being combative in this fashion is helpful to the question asker.

Comment: And I don't think avoiding the *core question* helps either. Details in the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5521/discussion-between-conspicuous-compiler-and-deceze). :)

Comment: @deceze: If you have a question you wish to have answered, I would suggest posting it so others might assist you.  I'm afraid I am uninterested in continuing engaging with you here.  Cheers!